# getElementById and querySelectorAll don't work in chrome://history

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm trying to simplify my life a bit and delete chrome history by query. I have several hundreds of checkboxes to delete and it's real pain to do it manually.

So I open `chrome://history/?q=somequery`, and see a lot of checkboxes. I write:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[aria-checked]')
```

and it returns nothing. Ok, I write:

```
document.querySelectorAll('button')
```

and it returns nothing! Ok, then I just hit `Edit HTML` button and add some element manually and then try to get it by id:
[image]

```
document.getElementById('foooobar')
```

And you know what? Nothing.

I don't understand if it's using some kind of frame or something that prevent me from accessing these elements, but I checked that there is no i-/frame, so I'm just confused why it doesn't work as expected.

I googled before asking and found several answers, where people just want to get elements before they are created, but now page is fully loaded and elements are still unavailable...

Comment: It is a Polymer app. Polymer uses web components which in turn create shadow dom. Is more complex than basic dom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reach into the shadow dom by using the ::shadow pseudoselector. Try this snippet to select all buttons.

```
[].slice.call(document
            .querySelector('history-app::shadow iron-pages history-list')
            .querySelector('history-list::shadow iron-list')
            .querySelectorAll('iron-list history-item'))
        .forEach(function(el) {
            console.log(el.querySelector('history-item::shadow button'))
        });
```

Comment: I heard that shadow dom still an experimental technology. I didn't expect they already used it.

Comment: It was way more experimental a year or two ago, now it has a lot of uses and browsers even use it internally for elements. You can see it if you enable it in your respective inspector.

Comment: IIUC the ::shadow (and /deep/) selectors are deprecated since Chrome 45, and doesn't seem to work as for today (Chrome 84)
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/10/remove-shadow-piercing